# Converting unix epoch timestamp column in every row using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, timestamps

I have a file with the following input sample data:

```
1137921146.499 180900 61.153.158.197 1409 
1137921158.698 181622 61.153.158.197 1409
1137921758.163 180026 221.226.124.114 1374
1137921802.016 179485 121.13.128.132 1409
```

the 1st column is unix epoch timestamp which i need to convert to human readable format plus i want the data to be delimited as follows

```
Sun Jan 22 01:12:26 PST 2006|180900|61.153.158.197|1409   
Sun Jan 22 01:12:38 PST 2006|181622|61.153.158.19|1409
```

i tried to add delimeters using sed 's/ {1,}/|/g' and converting the date using date -d @1137921146.499. But i am unable to club these two together in one command..

Comment: Downvoted because the problem consists of two separate problems and each can be found simply via a quick search.

Comment: After the edit it's okay, I think. He knows how to solve each problem, but not how to do combine it

Answer (score 10):

You can use awk program like this:

```
awk '{ print strftime("%c",$1)"|" $2"|"$3"|"$4 }' file
```

the core is to use strftime function to convert epoch to date format

Here is the output:

```
#awk '{ print strftime("%c",$1)"|" $2"|"$3"|"$4 }' file
Sun Jan 22 10:12:26 2006|180900|61.153.158.197|1409
Sun Jan 22 10:12:38 2006|181622|61.153.158.197|1409
Sun Jan 22 10:22:38 2006|180026|221.226.124.114|1374
Sun Jan 22 10:23:22 2006|179485|121.13.128.132|1409
```

P.S. Or you can use implicit output delimiter:

```
awk  'BEGIN { OFS="|"} {$1= strftime("%c",$1) }1' file
```

Comment: This is good. What if you don't know how many columns there are? can you put $2*  or similar to say 'for column 2 and after'?

Comment: @majorgear, the second example I provide deal with unknown number of columns

Comment: I missed that! It works great. thx

Answer (score 2):

Using what you already know:

- GNU `date` can convert a timestamp to a formatted date by giving it `@timestamp`.
- Replacing spaces by `|` will give you the output you want.

To that, we add

- GNU `date` may operate on a file, converting dates in one batch.

To batch convert dates with GNU `date` we have to extract the timestamps and prefix them with `@`:

```
$ sed 's/^\([^ ]*\).*$/@\1/' data.in
@1137921146.499
@1137921158.698
@1137921758.163
@1137921802.016
```

The `sed` expression substitutes each line with the first space-delimited field prefixed with `@`.

With `bash` (and `ksh93`, or any shell that understands process substitutions):

```
$ date -f <( sed 's/^\([^ ]*\).*$/@\1/' data.in )
Sun Jan 22 10:12:26 CET 2006
Sun Jan 22 10:12:38 CET 2006
Sun Jan 22 10:22:38 CET 2006
Sun Jan 22 10:23:22 CET 2006
```

Then we need to take the other fields of the input data and replace the delimiters:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 2- data.in | tr ' ' '|'
180900|61.153.158.197|1409
181622|61.153.158.197|1409
180026|221.226.124.114|1374
179485|121.13.128.132|1409
```

Then we paste these two things together with a `|` as delimiter:

```
$ paste -d '|' <( date -f <( sed 's/^\([^ ]*\).*$/@\1/' data.in ) ) <( cut -d ' ' -f 2- data.in | tr ' ' '|' )
Sun Jan 22 10:12:26 CET 2006|180900|61.153.158.197|1409
Sun Jan 22 10:12:38 CET 2006|181622|61.153.158.197|1409
Sun Jan 22 10:22:38 CET 2006|180026|221.226.124.114|1374
Sun Jan 22 10:23:22 CET 2006|179485|121.13.128.132|1409
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with your shell:

```
while read timestamp pid ip port; do
  echo "$(date -d @$timestamp)|$pid|$ip|$port"
done <yourfile
```